# Angular 8 Routing + Navigation: Locking a Component

Tags: angular, routes

I have built a Authentication system in Angular and was wondering how to lock a route that I have built. In order to get to the "members" route, you need to have an user account. How would you block getting to this route as you could just type the route into URL. I want to prevent this as you need to be a user of the system before being able to route to this page.

Please let me know if you need any chunks of code,
thanks.

Comment: Check for route guards

Comment: Check about the canActivate route guard [here](https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/routing/router-guards/). You have to check the validity of the user in this method and return a Boolean value. Then Angular will restrict this route if the user is invalid.

Answer (score 3):

[Route Guards](https://angular.io/guide/router#guards) is what you want. You define a guard function and then set what routes are governed by it in configuration. Works well.

Comment: Great that something like this exists. I will look into it, thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use a route guard. It`s a service that will check for you specific condition to enable or not a route. You use it on your routes file, like this one:

```
export const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: Component,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
  }
]
```

'canActivate' receives an array of your guards, in this case one. And you make your AuthGuard like this:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {

  constructor(
    private router: Router
  ) {}

  canActivate(): boolean {
      return \\ your logic to check user logged in
  }
}
```